# Need some Ruby translated

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

```
plist_values['HashData'].join("").unpack('m')[0].each_byte do |b|
    hash_decoded << sprintf("%02X", b)
end
```

I need to translate it to other language. As I understood, it puts all contents of 'HashData' array into a string, then decodes it from Base64, But what's next?
Can you write me a step-by step explanation what it does?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I've answered the question but to fit this into the SO system and make the answer useful to other visitors, it would be better to ask a specific question, at least in the title. Something like "What does unpack('m') do?".  Then someone can google it or get a related question answered. If you don't mind, certain other contributors can edit your question and generalize it a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `join("")` concatenates all the strings in the array (or what each element in the array returns when calling `to_s`).
- `unpack('m')` from the [docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#unpack-method) decodes the string (and it assumes it is base64 encoded).
- `sprintf("%02X", b)` from the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) returns the hexadecimal representation with upper case letters.
- `hash_decoded << ..` appends the hex representation to the string

The bottom line is that you get a string that represents the hexadecimal version (with upper case letters) of the joined strings in `plist_values['HashData']`.

Comment: But it *doesn't* encode the String into base64, it *decodes* base64 back into the (presumably) original String.

Comment: @DigitalRoss You're right. I don't know what I was thinking. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

It decodes a base64 value from `plist_values` (the one with key `'HashData'`) and converts it to printable hex.